# How to fit this function with ggplot?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have this code, that produce the underlying plot:

```
ggplot(data = df.wind, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(fill="gray70")+theme_gray()+
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", 
     shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE)
```

where df.wind is a data.frame with two melt column, with x variable and y values (nrow=1564)

```
dput(head(df.wind, 100))


structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1.1", 
"1.4", "1.6", "1.7", "1.8", "1.9", "2", "2.1", "2.2", "2.3", 
"2.4", "2.5", "2.6", "2.7", "2.8", "2.9", "3", "3.1", "3.2", 
"3.3", "3.4", "3.5", "3.6", "3.7", "3.8", "3.9", "4", "4.1", 
"4.2", "4.3", "4.4", "4.5", "4.6", "5"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.00648136404831617, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0568710218569573, 
0.0331350764009738, 0.000778567742181346, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("variable", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

x variable are from 1.1 to 5 (see the plot belowe).
The red point in the plot are the mean value of boxplot. Now, i would like to fit this function on the red point (mean values) in ggplot:

```
f.1 <- function(x) {0.20*exp(-1/2*(x-2.44)^2/0.44^2)}
```

I try with:

```
 stat_function(fun=f.1)
```

but the results is:

[image]

I would like a plot like this: [image]
but with ggplot, with standard deviation in gray smoothed shape, can you help me?

the input (before the melt) are:

```
#the melt is : 
#df.wind <- melt(df.first) 
> df.first
   1.1 1.4          1.6          1.7          1.8          1.9           2          2.1          2.2          2.3          2.4          2.5          2.6
1  0.006481364  NA 0.0568710219 0.0002457609 3.871170e-01 2.200518e-02 0.005475164 1.826136e-01 1.947184e-01 0.5896813676 2.232600e-01 0.3225219218 5.608991e-01
2           NA  NA 0.0331350764 0.0046640489 1.843779e-01 1.749766e-01 0.191004819 1.193214e-01 2.962062e-01 0.3851783671 6.182950e-03 0.5348332898 4.677831e-03
3           NA  NA 0.0007785677 0.2175048788 2.346405e-01 1.039406e-01 0.001825656 2.269029e-01 2.833296e-02 0.4138489953 9.377955e-04 0.0669620460 1.536969e-01
4           NA  NA           NA 0.2027838961 2.504343e-05 4.234387e-03 0.380774453 2.370194e-01 2.915897e-01 0.0599432588 3.597421e-02 0.0227235796 3.130949e-04
5           NA  NA           NA 0.0367588055 2.807767e-03 1.043797e-01 0.095845304 2.650026e-01 3.288862e-01 0.2526289542 1.587802e-01 0.2029812664 3.032966e-01
6           NA  NA           NA 0.0001293493 5.342767e-03 1.769321e-03 0.113826202 1.683836e-02 4.439024e-02 0.3283661206 2.169965e-01 0.0986317353 6.965810e-03
7           NA  NA           NA 0.0006016244 1.585400e-05 1.343501e-02 0.151902423 2.279927e-02 3.106943e-01 0.2191588897 2.025941e-01 0.2591057730 9.564509e-02
8           NA  NA           NA 0.0003273569 5.325572e-02 7.717559e-03 0.001200171 2.025384e-01 6.217285e-02 0.0739923928 1.475138e-01 0.0490003961 4.181948e-04
9           NA  NA           NA           NA 1.278425e-03 7.333455e-05 0.006748834 2.437205e-01 2.086699e-01 0.3121729942 1.604040e-01 0.1522214138 2.760602e-01
10          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA 3.831140e-02 0.094883403 3.649736e-01 3.076180e-01 0.0249218123 3.161318e-02 0.1027799792 4.707866e-02
11          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA 0.601483711 1.289741e-01 3.144645e-01 0.2694828722 1.499636e-01 0.0002089831 5.267470e-02
12          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA 0.004431897 1.679061e-01 2.336073e-01 0.0080753440 1.148124e-01 0.0002318349 4.456481e-02
13          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 8.714860e-02 1.368767e-05 0.3077823053 6.334479e-02 0.1301838300 1.609331e-02
14          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 2.350875e-01 2.356636e-01 0.0224159440 4.949959e-02 0.2966093282 8.454459e-02
15          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 2.384074e-02 5.570163e-02 0.4247469808 3.452081e-01 0.3216333776 4.160845e-02
16          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 1.264587e-01 8.635376e-03 0.1347697166 4.080500e-01 0.0001647543 2.631321e-01
17          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 1.420702e-02 5.428180e-02 0.6103309658 3.911007e-01 0.1509425436 1.489941e-01
18          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 2.103427e-01 3.737007e-01 0.3007014279 4.938125e-01 0.3973828526 3.383276e-02
19          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 2.554504e-01 1.147018e-02 0.0002265803 4.591925e-03 0.3572377602 3.123913e-03
20          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 5.577335e-05 2.335174e-01 0.0012259679 4.286238e-01 0.0161561379 3.614286e-03
21          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 1.667312e-04 1.073280e-02 0.7883638555 8.441154e-05 0.6982952461 4.818615e-01
22          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 4.001766e-02 2.752639e-05 0.4168715366 8.879262e-02 0.0996059651 5.569416e-01
23          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 2.664961e-01 1.072301e-01 0.3107491289 6.056280e-02 0.4275775383 1.234737e-01
24          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 4.255213e-03 7.977676e-03 0.5816519028 1.002626e-04 0.0353262065 5.315425e-01
25          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 6.163023e-04 1.837984e-01 0.7605576498 8.716455e-02 0.2690340651 3.893844e-01
26          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 6.254674e-01           NA 0.0037816680 1.270891e-01 0.7090851147 1.430902e-01
27          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 1.255314e-04           NA 0.0003029731 1.506215e-04 0.2948073844 4.800682e-04
28          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 1.108163e-03           NA 0.2367400881 1.597357e-03 0.0188122801 3.765104e-05
29          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 2.554425e-03           NA 0.3832140107 1.014310e-02 0.0871446820 5.907831e-05
30          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 2.530984e-01           NA 0.0576820845 3.921193e-03           NA 6.753260e-02
31          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 1.391381e-01           NA 0.3609909332 1.000000e+00           NA 3.704665e-05
32          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA 3.565458e-05           NA           NA 7.390058e-02           NA 2.167710e-01
33          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 3.837534e-01           NA 4.893506e-01
34          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 1.616508e-01           NA 4.865724e-02
35          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 9.098772e-01           NA 1.789785e-03
36          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 4.470068e-01           NA 2.031151e-01
37          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 4.830038e-01           NA 2.219624e-02
38          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 1.241570e-02           NA 2.260588e-01
39          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 5.432443e-04           NA 6.782484e-01
40          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 4.520105e-03           NA 5.582500e-01
41          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA 4.243905e-01
42          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA 2.995666e-02
43          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA 1.474023e-02
44          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA 6.399836e-01
45          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA 1.491312e-03
46          NA  NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA 6.471179e-01
            2.7          2.8          2.9            3          3.1          3.2          3.3          3.4          3.5          3.6          3.7          3.8         3.9
1  4.499662e-04 4.308965e-01 0.1846289754 0.1495882052 6.437727e-03 1.754048e-05 0.1393672129 0.0001247298 0.0004091646 5.839879e-02 0.0135808849 0.0547941581 0.020006029
2  1.306869e-01 2.861627e-01 0.0841788570 0.0007794227 2.786660e-01 6.188519e-02 0.0969532654 0.0175693273 0.0516393173 1.744447e-02 0.0757759423 0.0055829809 0.002544278
3  3.336478e-01 1.896727e-01 0.1866402182 0.2341742385 2.087043e-01 1.100505e-02 0.0546199912 0.0131491746 0.0332847618 2.534892e-03 0.0179282760 0.0004245233 0.001469554
4  2.830717e-01 1.067222e-01 0.2813401463 0.0015782953 1.041643e-04 1.003798e-01 0.0512842982 0.0112158358 0.0023525605 2.652773e-02 0.0092351396           NA          NA
5  1.934817e-01 1.745480e-01 0.2480641519 0.0071154953 9.463470e-04 2.651030e-02 0.0001757652 0.0498236007 0.1768925514 9.057567e-03 0.0006734735           NA          NA
6  2.628157e-01 8.548378e-02 0.0750665697 0.0989676920 1.153380e-04 7.905279e-02 0.0287358828 0.0001157812 0.0086979789 5.038585e-05           NA           NA          NA
7  1.825299e-02 1.687716e-01 0.0322639113 0.0811943959 3.659172e-04 3.108384e-04 0.0800617978 0.0001046283 0.0003794121           NA           NA           NA          NA
8  4.365543e-05 5.042217e-02 0.0346419790 0.0105210803 6.637921e-05 1.126566e-02 0.0917971146 0.0400625240           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
9  2.064168e-01 1.831961e-02 0.0623602459 0.0267009176 2.111716e-03 1.251065e-01 0.0002682661 0.0000352683           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
10 1.369157e-01 1.818023e-01 0.0009934843 0.0017759396 1.987876e-04 2.673977e-01           NA 0.0040503935           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
11 2.447317e-01 3.944215e-02 0.2122951249 0.0240529727 3.126166e-04 2.539193e-01           NA 0.0006627692           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
12 7.528366e-02 8.125089e-05 0.0332381395 0.0137881345           NA 1.188077e-04           NA 0.0001098824           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
13 4.086752e-03 2.821779e-01 0.4631477592 0.2654398549           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
14 3.345307e-01 1.389398e-04 0.1540744209 0.1643144661           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
15 1.991549e-01 3.299329e-01 0.3394782692 0.0030171718           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
16 1.437708e-03 4.952253e-01 0.4763051089 0.1909704485           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
17 6.435376e-05 7.593932e-05 0.0988324122 0.0002964738           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
18 2.932503e-01 1.890247e-02 0.0017489274 0.0109076578           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
19 4.773677e-01 4.435161e-01 0.1552828208 0.0001522862           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
20 4.190843e-01 9.612338e-05 0.2890716709 0.0001810531           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
21 5.624247e-03           NA 0.0016066623           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
22 1.370349e-02           NA 0.0009029369           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
23 2.947277e-03           NA 0.0012422839           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
24 2.104341e-01           NA 0.0002637792           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
25           NA           NA 0.0382562883           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
26           NA           NA 0.0241366774           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
27           NA           NA 0.0852539202           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
28           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
29           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
30           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
31           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
32           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
33           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
34           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
35           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
36           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
37           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
38           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
39           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
40           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
41           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
42           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
43           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
44           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
45           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
46           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          NA
             4       4.1         4.2          4.3        4.4 4.5         4.6          5
1  0.001269770 0.2891099 0.003761482 0.0008819435 0.04863082  NA 0.003254704 0.00678208
2  0.003180993        NA          NA 0.0071604527         NA  NA 0.013918034         NA
3  0.024833000        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
4  0.001493825        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
5  0.000069243        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
6           NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
7           NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
8           NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
9           NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
10          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
11          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
12          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
13          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
14          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
15          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
16          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
17          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
18          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
19          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
20          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
21          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
22          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
23          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
24          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
25          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
26          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
27          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
28          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
29          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
30          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
31          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
32          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
33          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
34          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
35          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
36          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
37          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
38          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
39          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
40          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
41          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
42          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
43          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
44          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
45          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
46          NA        NA          NA           NA         NA  NA          NA         NA
>
```

Comment: Is your `variable` column a character vector, a factor, or numeric?

Comment: the variable colum is a factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `variable` column is a factor, your `f.1` function is treating it as integers (1.1 becoming 1, 1.4 becoming 2, 1.6 becoming 3, and so on). It is also distorting the gaps in the x-axis (notice that 1.1 is the same distance from 1.4 as 1.4 is from 1.6).

To fix this, you can:

- Change your `variable` column to be numeric beforehand
- Add `group=variable` to your aesthetics. This is necessary to create a boxplot when the x-axis is numeric.

Code:

```
df.wind$variable <- as.numeric(as.character(df.wind$variable))

ggplot(data = df.wind, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=variable)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="gray70")+theme_gray()+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE) +
  stat_function(fun=f.1)
```

Comment: sorry, but i don't undertand, it's doesn't work, i mean, the result with as.nmeric etc.. is the same, the curve no fit red point mean values

Comment: @skylobo Could you edit your question to include `dput(head(df.wind, 100))`, as well as what `v.2.44` is, to make your problem reproducible?

Comment: I edit the question. The v.2.44 was an error, the real value is 2.44 (without v, sorry!)

Comment: @skylobo Thanks! I've fixed my solution as well, please see if it works for you.

Comment: Can you imagine also how to put  the shape standard deviation of the curve on the graph?

Comment: @skylobo Sure, you probably want to use `geom_ribbon` for that, but it depends on the function that calculates it. If you edit the details (the inputs) into your question it may help.